# line wrapping is adding unwanted prefix text

Tags: wrapping

Somehow, I must have clicked something that makes my line wrap (<kbd>M-q</kbd>) insert text. Here is an example:

line I want to wrap:

```
- also copied it into the loop that gets executed every time - now we always get degraded results!
```

results of wrapping:

```
- also copied it into the loop that gets executed every time - now we
- so it is something to do with unlocking/reset/locking mechanism ..always
- so it is something to do with unlocking/reset/locking mechanism ..get
- so it is something to do with unlocking/reset/locking mechanism ..degraded
- so it is something to do with unlocking/reset/locking mechanism ..results!
```

How do I turn this off??

Answer (score 1):

Ugh, finally figured out what I did! I hit <kbd>C-x .</kbd> at the end of a line -> this invokes `set-fill-prefix`, and applied the entire line. To undo this I moved to the beginning of a line and hit <kbd>C-x .</kbd> again. This cancelled the fill prefix.